# How to get Amenities for a place using google place api or place data api

Tags: google-places-api

I could able to get details about the restaurant using google place detail api, but I need to get Amenities particularly. The Api I use is mentioned below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

You can't get amenities information from this API. They don't give you access to that information on purpose because Google Maps must have a competitive advantage. So, you can link the restaurant to that location on Google Maps in order give the option to view the amenities.